# Interacting with external program

Tags: windows

During my work I need to perform some routine actions in program. So I'm looking for a way to automate the process. The program/script have to be able to run an external program (executable file in windows 10) and press on couple of buttons. Would like to hear suggestions from you.
Sorry for a lame question.

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow: tool recommendation and non-programming question (OS-functionality questions would fit better on SuperUser, but even there, this question would be closed).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For windows try AutoIt. See this tutorial: https://www.autoitscript.com/ https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/tutorials/notepad/notepad.htm